# Trying to make a todolist using mongodb and express with node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I keep getting and this error      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null

when i run my code using express with node trying to run my todolist and this error keeps poping up preventing me from adding any new items on the custom todolist
And the issue according to terminal is one this line code specifically

```
**else {
   List.findOne({Name: listName},function(err, foundList){
      foundList.items.push(item);
      foundList.save();
      res.redirect("/"+ listName)
const itemsSchema = {
  Name:String
}**
```

And here is the whole code

```
const Item = mongoose.model("Item",itemsSchema)
    
    const item1 = new Item({
      Name:"Welcome to your todolist!"
    });
    
    const item2 = new Item({
      Name:"Hit the + button to add new items"
    });
    
    const item3 = new Item({
      Name:"Example: I have to study X today"
    });
    
    const defaultItems = [item1,item2,item3];
    
    
    const listSchema = {
      Name:String,
      items:[itemsSchema]
    };
    
    const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);
    
    
    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    
      Item.find({},function(err,foundItems){
    
            if(foundItems.length===0){
    
              Item.insertMany(defaultItems,function(err){
            if(err){
              console.log(err)
            }else {
              console.log("Items saved successfully")
            }
          })
          res.redirect("/");
    
          }else {
            res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems});
    
          }
      });
    });
     
        app.get("/:customListName",function(req,res){
            const customListName = req.params.customListName;
    
          List.findOne({Name:customListName}, function(err,foundList){
            if(!err){
              if(!foundList){
                const list = new List({
                  Name: customListName,
                  items: defaultItems
                });
              list.save();
              res.redirect("/" + customListName);
                      } else {
                        res.render("list", {listTitle: foundList.Name, newListItems: foundList.items})
                }
            }
          })
    
        });
    
    
    app.post("/", function(req, res){
    
     const itemName = req.body.newItem;
     const listName = req.body.list;
    
     const item = new Item({
       Name:itemName
     });
    
     if(listName==="Today"){
      item.save();
    
      res.redirect("/");
     }else {
       List.findOne({Name: listName},function(err, foundList){
          foundList.items.push(item);
          foundList.save();
          res.redirect("/"+ listName)
    
       })
     }
    
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is stating that the object you're trying to access with `.item` is not defined, in this case `foundList`

```
else {
    List.findOne({Name: listName},function(err, foundList){
        if(!err && foundList) {
            foundList.items.push(item);
            foundList.save();
            res.redirect("/"+ listName)
        } else return (err ? res.status(500).json(err.message) : res.status(404).json("List not found"); // or however you want to handle errors 
    })
}
```

You should be checking if the `foundList` is defined and whether an error exists inside that callback prior to using that object.